# Export TileMill project as SVG image with CartoCSS applied to it

Tags: openstreetmap, leaflet, tilemill

I am able to export `TileMill` project as `mbtiles` and rendering tiles on map using `leaflet` which is working fine. But if I export the project as `SVG or PNG` image the CartoCSS which I have written is not applying for the image. 
So how to export `tilemill` project as SVG image with CartoCSS applied to it.

This is the image in `tileMill`[image: tile mill project]

This is the exported png image.

[image: Project exported as png image]

Comment: would be helpful to see a photo of how the map renders in TileMill and how it renders exported as .svg and .png.  Errors with export to .png is particularly surprising, as .mbtiles is essentially just a bunch of .png files.  Haven't run into problems myself with print exports.

Comment: @JamesConkling Like u said.. Its surprising. I have updated problem with images. In mbtiles I have png images with CartoCss applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, it appears that the only styles missing are the styles that rely on a zoom level. When exported in MBtiles, your "map" is seen in a map context where you have zoom levels, and as such, your styles are rightfully applied. However, when exporting a static map, by default there is no zoom level applied during rendering.

I've snooped a bit and found this issue on TileMill repository, which would correspond to your problem: https://github.com/mapbox/tilemill/issues/1819

Unfortunately, the fix (under the form of a `static_zoom` parameter in the command-line) doesn't seem to be in the last "official" release available of TileMill, but if you install it from the source on GitHub, it should be OK; something along the lines of `./index.js export help` should tell you about this `static_zoom` parameter.

Of course, another solution would be to comment out the conditions the zoom, to always apply the styles you want, and export afterwards.

Comment: Your last solution "`comment out the conditions the zoom`" works. About `static_zoom` do u mean `it is possible to export as `svg` with `conditional CartoCSS ` at different zoom levels??

Comment: I didn't test it, but it seems it is the case; according to the help, `static_zoom` "explicity sets the zoom level of the static map". Unfortunately since TileMill hasn't seen an official release in some time, you'd have to get a version from the last version of the code ( https://github.com/mapbox/tilemill#installation )